# Proving Continuity Through Open Subsets

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 4x+1$ is continuous. I want to prove this through the lens of topology. The definition of continuity that I would like to use is:

If for each open subset of $V$ of $\mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Intuitively I know that $f(x)$ is continuous, but using this definition I am lost as to how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much easier way would be via composition of continuous functions, or even through the equivalent sequence formulation. But the argument goes like this:

let $U$ be open in the image. So for $x\in f^{-1}(U)$, $y=f(x) \in U$ which is open, so we can find a $B_\epsilon (y) \subset U$. Now $f^{-1} (B_\epsilon (y)) = (\frac{y-\epsilon-1}{4},\frac{y+\epsilon-1}{4})$ which is open in $f^{-1}(U)$. So $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an open set of $\mathbb R$. Then $A$ is the union of a set $\{(a_\lambda,b_\lambda)\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ of open intervals. So,$$f^{-1}(A)=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\left(\frac14a_\lambda-\frac14,\frac14b_\lambda-\frac14\right),$$which is an open set, since it is the union of open sets.